# I am trying to upload a files to github using node.js

Tags: node.js, database, git, api, github

Basically I want to use github as a files database for content that is user generated.

Need help to upload file to my github repo using node js

I tried looking through the Github rest API but the documentation just got me lost.... any help?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Github API documentation, you need to use *repositories* API.

- **[Create or update file contents](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/contents?apiVersion=2022-11-28#create-or-update-file-contents)**

> Creates a new file or replaces an existing file in a repository. You must authenticate using an access token with the workflow scope to use this endpoint.

So basically in code, it would be something like this:

```js
const axios = require('axios');

const data = JSON.stringify({
  message: 'my commit message',
  committer: {
    name: <name>,
    email: <email>
  },
  content: Buffer.from('some content').toString('base64')
});

const config = {
  method: 'put',
  url: 'https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo}/contents/{path}',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer {YOUR-TOKEN}',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  data: data
};

axios(config)
  .then(response => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```